# jQuery each element

Tags: jquery

I'm curious why this code is invalid:

```
$.each( $("p") ).css("color", "green");
```

While this code works fine:

```
$.each($("p"), function() { $(this).css("color", "green") });
```

Is it not possible to chain elements with each?

Comment: No, it's not possible like that. Here's an existing SO discussion about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002394/jquery-animate-each-chaining

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Remove the wrapper:

```
$("p").css("color", "green");
```

If you want to use `$.each`, specify a function as a second argument:

```
$("p").each(function() {
//Or: $.each( $("p"), function() {
   $(this).css("color", "green");
});
```

The jQuery method automatically returns an instance of the collection, so chaining should still be possible.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pC2Bj/**

See also:

- jQuery docs - [`$().each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- jQuery docs - [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: It should be noted that `$.each` is used for `HTMLCollections` and other native JavaScript collections while the jQuery method `$('.selector').each()` is used for jQuery objects.

Answer (score 9):

`$.each()` requires a function as the second argument. You've only passed one argument.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

> ### jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )
>
> **collection** The object or array to iterate over.
>
> **callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement)** The function that will be executed on every object.

---

Yes, it is possible to chain, since `$.each` returns the collection you're iterating.

```
$.each($("p"), function() { $(this).css("color", "green") }).addClass('test');
```

Comment: Could you give an example of chaining each?

Comment: @Toast: Updated with an example.

Comment: @Toast. I wish you were right, But my answer was wrong. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/qSquu/1/) JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

`$.each` requires two parameters, the second being a callback that executes once for each element. If you don't pass the callback parameter, `$.each` won't work.

Also, `$.each` returns the object over which it iterates, so chaining doesn't work like it would with methods that return a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Note that no version of `each` is needed to achieve the (most likely) desired effect.

```
$("p").css("color", "green");
```

does the job.